# How can I test the markup validity of a string (webpage) in .Net?

Tags: asp.net, validation, testing, markup, doctype

I've written a VB.Net page to browse my site. It stores the HttpWebResponse in a string. How can I validate the markup validity of the page in .Net? - something similar to W3's validate by direct input option. I'm looking for something that can identify the DOCTYPE, validate it yes or no, and return a list of failures I can display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's some information on how to that: **[Validate XHTML in C#](http://dotnetperls.com/Content/XHTML-Validator.aspx)** (you should be to translate this into VB.NET if needed).

There's also a **[validator module](http://www.thejoyofcode.com/XHTML_Validator_For_All.aspx)** available for download. The only drawback is that the string has to be saved into a physical html file.

Comment: @José, I used both links. I translated the code in the first link to VB and tweaked it a bit to validate HTML in automated crawls of my site. It works OK - it does some basic checking.

Now the module in the second link is just cool. Very slick, very easy. It can validate additional HTML/Pages in my dev environment that an autonomous crawl can't access.

I also overrode MyBase.Render to capture all output (of course I can turn this on and off), save it to a file, and run it through an automated validator later - to catch unique HTML a particular user might see.

Very useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The W3C have a [experimental API](http://validator.w3.org/docs/api.html) that can accept code fragments that might be of use, and there are other [3rd Party web services](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WebService-Validator-HTML-W3C/) (though I'm not sure if they can accept fragments) as well.

I'm afraid I have ever used these myself so I can't comment on their effectiveness...